# Weblogic Deployment Error :No Handler for OWSM Security Policy found

Tags: weblogic, jdeveloper, weblogic12c

I am trying to deploy a adf faces project(war) to weblogic 12.1.3. Bu it returns fallowing error:

> Error javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: No Handler for OWSM Security
>
> Policy found. Error No Handler for OWSM Security Policy found

How can I solve this problem.

Weblogic logs:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cd80ebb6f72c95432c6c
.

Comment: You also have `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.adf.share.weblogic.WLSThreadLocalManager` and `no metadata found for metadata object "/META-INF/adf-config.xml" 
MDS-00201: PDocument not found in MetadataStore` errors... so it's very hard to know what's going wrong. Did you install EM on your WebLogic domain together with a MDS repository or use WebLogic11g with OSB and the OWSM add-on?

Comment: And please tell us the Jdev version the application was build with! H as the wls set up with the right adf runtime?

Comment: Same version 12.1.3. I created wls domain only choosing basic wls domain . I didn't choose em during domain configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Reconfigure your WebLogic domain and include Oracle WSM Policy Manager.